# EF 5.x DbContext Fluent Generator

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I ran the EF 5.x DbContext Fluent Generator to generate my code first files and mappings.  What I would like is to have all the generated classes include a base interface IEntity. I am also thinking about an abstract base class EntityBase with with properties for Id and rowVersion. I am sure a lot of people have done this but i cant seem to find it in my searches

So for example all my entities would look like this

partial class Person : EntityBase, IEntity

thanks

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am far from an expert, so treat this with caution.

You have the right idea, just create a partial class and put the inheritance/interface references in that one.

You don't modify the generated classes at all, that's the beauty of partial classes.